# Why was the "Anime no Chikara" project interrupted?

Tags: anime-production, anime-no-chikara

Back in the 2010, TV Tokyo's anime department and Aniplex began a project called *[Anime no Chikara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime_no_Chikara)*. After producing three anime with original stories, [Sora no Woto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_of_the_Sky), [Senkou no Night Raid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senkou_no_Night_Raid) and [Occult Academy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occult_Academy), the project was put on break and never resumed.

The president of Aniplex [Koichiro Natsume said in 2012](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interview/2012-12-19/aniplex-koichiro-natsume/), "unfortunately I cannot say that this was a success", but he didn't say exactly what was wrong with the project.

Are there any sources or data explaining why *Anime no Chikara* was aborted? Is this suspension related to *Senkou no Night Raid* controversies regarding the interpretation of [Manchurian incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukden_Incident), causing the [episode 7 to be released online only](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=207499) or there are more practical reasons behind this decision?

Comment: Because it wasn't financial and popularity success?

Comment: I tend to agree with Euphoric here. I think the series that were a part of it just weren't successful. Unfortunately I can't find any viewership numbers to back this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that Koichiro Natsume said was that it was a one year project. It's difficult to tell from what he said if it was planned to be one year from the start or if it ended up being one year, but if it was planned to be one year, then it wasn't aborted but instead just ended.

One thing that he said was that there were supposed to be four projects. Only three were released, which may have been the failure that he was talking about.

In regards to episode 7, they actually played a replacement episode (episode 7.5) the same day that episode 7 would be released, so they actually did have an episode that day. From reading about it, it doesn't seem as though they were forced to stream it online but chose to instead, but it is difficult to tell.

It is difficult to tell exactly how voluntary ending the program was, but Koichiro Natsume at least implies in his [interview](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interview/2012-12-19/aniplex-koichiro-natsume/) that it was intended or at least ended up more as a learning tool than anything else.